# Module federation display a blank page for a few seconds when a remote is unavailable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have a micro frontend React application using Webpack module federation. My setup is an `host` application and a `remote1` application.

Since I configured "react" as a shared dependency between the 2 apps, I found out that if `remote1` is unavailable, the `host` application will display a **blank page** until the request for `remote1/remoteEntry.js` **script fail** after after a **few seconds**.

I wasn't expecting this behavior. I was **expecting** the `host` application to **render my React application immediatly** while Module Federation is **trying to load all the remotes** and show some kind of managed Spinner from my app.

It seems like the `host` application will not render until all the remotes script requests have resolved.

Is there any way to circumvent this behavior?

I made it work with [Dynamic Remote Containers](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#dynamic-remote-containers) but I would rather leverage [ModuleFederationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#modulefederationplugin-high-level) `remotes` config section.

Here's my config for the `host` app:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "host",
  remotes: {
    remote1: "remote1@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js"
  },
  shared: {
    "react": {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react"]
    },
    "react-dom": {
      singleton: true,
      eager: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"]
    },
  }
})
```

Here's my config for the `remote1` app:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "remote1",
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  exposes: {
    "./register": "./src/register"
  },
  shared: {
    "react": {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react"]
    },
    "react-dom": {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"]
    }
  }
})
```

Also, all my React bootstrapping code is in a `bootstrap.jsx` file included with a dynamic import from the `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution integrated with React is to use `Suspense`
From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) :
*React.Suspense lets you specify the loading indicator in case some components in the tree below it are not yet ready to render.*
Here is an example for how to host:

```
//App.jsx
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
const App1 = React.lazy(() => import("app1/App"));
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>I am the Container App!</h2>
            <Suspense fallback={"loading..."}>
                <App1/>
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Take aways:

- Suspense is built to support asynchronic operations (loading code, data, images, etc) though today, lazy loading components is the only use case supported.
- It also allows you to specify what to do (like a catch block!) until it's done - ie `<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>`

[Related read](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-react-suspense-works)