# Module federation display a blank page for a few seconds even using Suspense

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have a 2 React micro-frontend applications, one host and one remote, I'm able to load the remote app into the host using Lazy loading and Module Federation, like this:

```
const RemoteApp = lazy(() => import("Remote/App"));

export const App = () => (
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <RemoteApp />
    </ErrorBoundary>
);
```

Notice that I have an `ErrorBoundary` class to handle errors, so when the remote is not found after a few secons, it displays my custom error message.

But I want to customize the behavior when the remote app is not running.

In the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72638378/module-federation-display-a-blank-page-for-a-few-seconds-when-a-remote-is-unavai) I learned that I can use `Suspense` to display a fallback UI while the remote app is loading so I changed my code like this:

```
const RemoteApp = lazy(() => import("Remote/App"));

export const App = () => (
    <ErrorBoundary>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>} maxDuration={5000}>
            <RemoteApp />
        </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
);
```

But it doesn't have any effect, it still displays a blank page for a few secons and then it displays my custom error message from the `ErrorBoundary`, it is as if `Suspense` was not there at all. I also tried adding the `ErrorBoundary` inside `Suspense` but it doesn't have any effect either, it is the exact same result.